# @keyframes not working in Firefox or IE. Only on Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, animation, keyframe

The text in my p tag works with the @keyframes animation on Google Chrome, but does not work on Firefox and/or IE. I am running the latest version of Firefox and can't figure out why it does not work. Help would be appreciated. The text within the p tag should move in from the left side of the browser window, to the middle. Again, it works perfect in Chrome, but is static in Firefox and IE.

```
 h.h1 p {
 margin-top: 25px;
 font-size: 21px;
 text-align: center;

 animation-name: fromleft; 
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-timing-function: ease;


-moz-animation-name: fromleft; 
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease;

-webkit-animation-name: fromleft; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

-ms-animation-name: fromleft; 
-ms-animation-duration: 2s;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
 }


@keyframes fromleft {
0% { margin-left: -5000px; }
50%   { margin-left: 0px; }
100%   { margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fromleft {
  0% { margin-left: -5000px; }
50%   { margin-left: 0px; }
100%   { margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; }

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fromleft {
 0% { margin-left: -5000px; }
50%   { margin-left: 0px; }
100%   { margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; }
}

 /* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fromleft {
  0% { margin-left: -5000px; }
 50%   { margin-left: 0px; }
100%   { margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; }
}

 /* Firefox < 16 */
 @-moz-keyframes fromleft {
 0% { margin-left: -5000px; }
50%   { margin-left: 0px; }
100%   { margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; }
```

And here is my CSS

```
<div class="h1">
    <h1> Some Text </h1>

    <div>
    <p> Some Text </P>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `animation` (like `transition`) has troubles with `auto` values. But the following seems to work in current Firefox, just don't know if it fits your needs:

```
@keyframes fromleft {
  0% {
    margin-left: -5000px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
  }
}
```

Here is [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjMPXj).

In your example it makes no difference because the text is centered anyway. In other cases, you'll have to specify fixed values instead of `auto` either to the `<p>` itself or a wrapper.

Comment: That did it. I changed the code as per your comments and it works in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Good to know about the "auto". I played around with the code some more and removed all prefixes, -m0z, -o, -ms, -webkit etc. and the code still works on all 3 browsers. Are these prefixes only used and/or required so that the code can work on older versions of these browsers?